# PIL load RGB matrix of a grayscale image

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, python-imaging-library

How can I load the RGB matrix of an image. Basically, if I have a 224x224 image(grayscale), I need it's RGB matrix so I want a 224x224 matrix consisting of 3 element tuples. I have tried:

```
f="/path/to/grayscale/image"
image = Image.open(f)
new_width  = 224
new_height = 224
im = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im=np.array(im)
print(im)
```

and it prints:

```
[[195 195 195 ..., 101 104 105]
 [195 195 195 ..., 102 105 106]
 [194 194 194 ..., 104 109 111]
 ..., 
 [137 138 140 ..., 209 207 206]
 [133 134 136 ..., 209 207 206]
 [132 133 135 ..., 209 207 206]]
```

After some testing, I realised that it was because of the image being grayscale. How can I load the RGB matrix of a grayscale image?

Comment: If the image is grayscale it is grayscale, not RGB. There is no such *" the RGB matrix of a grayscale image"*. However, if what you want is to **create** a RGB image **from** your grayscale image, its quite easy, just repeat the matrix 3 times, creating a `NxMx3` `np.array`

Comment: Oh. Thanks! How can I do that?

Comment: I am lookign for it, but first: why do you want to do this? It may be better to continue using it as grayscale

Comment: Actually, I'm passing some images through a trained VGG model(Convolutional Neural Network) and it accepts only RGB pictures :D

Answer (score 3):

I am not proficien in PIL, but it looks there is an `image.Convert("RGB")` method that may or may not work, so give it a try.

However, if your intention is to continue using `np.array` then the following will work:

```
im=np.array(im)
imRGB = np.repeat(im[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
```

Basically it repeats the input `np.array` into a 3rd new axis, 3 times.

`imRGB[:,:,0]` is the Red channel

`imRGB[:,:,1]` is the Green channel

`imRGB[:,:,2]` is the Blue channel

Comment: +1. Don't make it too complicated, convert to RGB and then read the data, expect your REALLY need performance (i.e. processing a lot of images).

Comment: and for the alpha channel you probably DO NOT want to copy the grayscale value.

Comment: @Ander Biguri I need it to be a matrix of tuples like this: `[[[ 58  21  12]
  [ 57  20  11]
  [ 60  23  14]...]]
` `np.repeat` doesn't do this

Comment: @allo oops you are rigth

Comment: @Sibi ah, but that is a specific need you have, not the correct way of storing a RGB image, or converting a gray image to RGB (which is exactly what you asked). I suggest you accept this answer and open a new one about how to reshape a NxMx3 matrix into whatever you need. Probably something in the lines of `reshape`